I want LaTeX to handle word's before-after spaces automatically without me adding spaces
I am currently creating a LaTeX document dynamically with templates whereas I create a sentence in a loop with one or more words. The template for this sentence is He said: "<%words%>.".
The ending fullstop is there already and, also, the quotes. And I just fill in the words, replacing <%words%>.
And so I may end up with text like: He said: " word1 word2 ." Which is substandard because the spaces do appear and are ugly.
I want to avoid the spaces after the first quote and before the ending fullstop.
Please assume I can't fix the problem when I dynamically add the words. It must be fixed within LaTeX. I wanted LaTeX to handle the spaces. I thought this could work: "{}word1{}word2{}." But it does not. Perhaps I misunderstood the use of {}.
I also thought this could work: "\xspace{}word1\xspace{}word2\xspace{}.", but it does not.
Both, above, stick the words together, there is no space before, in-between or after.
The bottom line, and without confusing you with templates: I want to let LaTeX handle spacing (as it does and should) with myself just indicating word boundaries: e.g. He said: "{}word1{}word2{}." to render as He said: "word1 word2.".
Here is a test:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\begin{document}
He said: "{}word1{}word2{}."

He said: "\xspace{}word1\xspace{}word2\xspace{}."
\end{document}

btw, i really need this to work with xelatex if possible.
Edit: Sorry I think my example is too simple to convey the complexity. The problem is that I need to keep adding dynamically word1, word2 into my sentence. These (word1, word2) may be just words or control+words e.g. \emph{a b c} or \href{url}{caption}.
Secondly, there is no way to know if what follows word2 is punctuation (no space to add) or another word (so add a space).
Sorry If I was confusing.

well if your input doesn't do some curious things something like He said: ``\relax  word1 word2  \unskip.'' should work (and you should use the correct quotes, not ")

You've mentioned what the template looks like, as in He said: "<%words%>.".  But where does the replacement text come from (e.g., a file, a \def, etc.), and in what format may it be found?

let's say that the tex document is created on-the-fly by a computer program. Let's say that word1, word2 are what the program finds in a webpage which it scrapes.

it's more or less impossible to understand this question, why do you want to add {} (which does nothing useful here)  why not insert word1 word2 why insert anything at all between the words, and what do you want that inserted thing to do? As Ulrike says you should use \`and''for quotes and you can use\unskip` to remove a trailing space. Is there a remaining issue?

if you want to use xspace it would be \`word1\xspace word2\xspace .'' the{}stop\xspaceworking, but I can't see why you needxspace` here.

@DavidCarlisle, in my post the \xspace etc. were added just to show what I tried and did not work. My script keeps adding words or control+words (e.g. \emph{a b c} and a space at the end, without checking if it is needed or not. I don't want to parse me tex output and deal with what TeX can do better. So my tex output will contain superfluous spaces (e.g. before a punctuation or after opening quote, bracket etc.). And I want to tell TeX that these superfluous spaces can be removed by it. I am just using them to denote a word boundary and not an actual space that must be enforced.

it is really hard to guess what you are doing here but as far as I can guess, just add your fragment ending each with \xspace  (not \xspace{})  and it will probably do what you want

The question is far from clear but it seems you are looking for \xspace<space> rather than \xspace{} (which does nothing as {} explicitly prevents \xspace from acting).

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,xspace}
\begin{document}
He said: ``word1\xspace word2\xspace .''

He said: ``word1\xspace word2\xspace \emph{a b c}\xspace \href{url}{caption}\xspace .''

\end{document}


Great! thanks David. The only problem is when a word/control follows opening bracket/quotes. as it leaves extra space. But it is non-existent case for me anyway. However, the general question remains: how to tell TeX that this is a word boundary without space/punctuation. Ideally I was looking for something like: \wb{}Look\wb{}\emph{Mummy\wb{}!\wb{}no\wb{}}\wb{}\wb{}\wb{}Spaces\wb{}!. (where \wb{} -one or more- denotes a word boundary).

OT+shameless plug: https://metacpan.org/pod/LaTeX::Easy::Templates is a Perl package I published for making it easy to render Perl data into PDF via TeX (naturally!) using aforementioned templates. My posted question arose when I was building a news website scraper where it extracts the crucial bits, constructs the TeX document from a template usng this Perl module and renders it into PDF via pdflatex or xelatex for multilingual sites. thank you everybody, again.

@bliako I really have no idea what you mean by word boundary I know what it means in other contexts but tex does not deal in words. But there have been numerous requests that the question be clarified, but it is what it is, I suggest we leave this here and if you have more questions open a new question.

The conversion from HTML to latex is via a state machine and that makes it hard to keep track if spaces are needed before appending words/control into the produced latex document.

Yes, I will open a new question. Right now your solution works in most cases for me.

Please try to make the new question more comprehensible, this answer was a complete guess that it was related to your question, mostly based on the comments rather than the question itself. @bliako

New question here, hopefully clearer (sorry, I was trying to separate my context to the problem): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/715776/how-to-separate-words-in-tex-without-a-space-can-i-mark-word-boundaries-without

@bliako that isn't a new question you just asked the same question again and this post answers it again.

If your template is able to add \corrspaces control sequence just before the first ", i.e. it should look like He said: \corrspaces"<%words%>.", then the following macro solves your problem:
\def\corrspaces"#1#2."{``\removelastspace#1#2\end/ \end/\fin{#1#2}.''}
\def\removelastspace #1 \end/#2\fin#3{\ifx^#2^#3\else#1\fi}

He said (1): \corrspaces" word1 word2 ."

He said (2): \corrspaces"word1 word2 ."

He said (3): \corrspaces" word1 word2."

He said (4): \corrspaces"word1 word2." 

All four examples print the same result: “word1 word2.”

I am sorry but this is a quite complex script and I outlined only a simple case. I have not said that word1, word2 etc. can sometimes be an \href{url}{caption} or \emph{blah blah}. And so your solution gives me ! Use of \corrspaces doesn't match its definition. (with xelatex). Sorry. I thought it was something simple so I did not include the complex cases.

@bliako The \corrspaces must be followed by ". The error message says that it is not true in your case. It has nothing to do with the fact that some words are in the form  \href{url}{caption}.

yep, not all my cases are in the quoted examples of He said ....  Isn't there a way to just tell it that this is a word boundary? other than a space ?

@bliako Then you have to say more exactly, what does your template. The word boundary  isn't your problem. You want to remove optional space before a sequence of words and after them. And TeX must know where such a words sequence begins and where it ends. Your  question specifies, that the begin is " and the end is .". Now, you are saying somewhat different.

@bliako The template must say to TeX the boundary is processed words sequence. Without this, TeX is unable to remove the spaces at this unspecified boundary. For example the template can include \corrspaces{<%words%>} and in your presented example: He said: "\corrspaces{<%words%>}.". Note, the boundary is specified here by {...}. If this is true then we can slightly modify the current version of \corrspaces and your problem is solved.

I have edited my question to more accurately explain what I am trying to do. The he said... was just a simplistic example. The gist is: How can I tell TeX that it must ignore the space before the punctuation xyz . or \emph{a b c} . (note: space before .) or ignore the space between an opening quote or bracket etc. and a word or \emph{word}, because that space is put there by my script and there is no easy way for me to tell the script not to put the space there. Thank you
