How to separate words in TeX without a space? Can I mark word boundaries without spaces?
I want to be able to tell TeX that here is a word boundary without using spaces. And I want TeX to decide on adding space at the designated word boundary or not.
For example:
I want to remove spaces from this TeX string: ``Look \emph{Mummy! no} Spaces!'' and end up with something like this ``\wb{}Look\wb{}\emph{Mummy\wb{}!\wb{}no\wb{}}\wb{}\wb{}\wb{}Spaces\wb{}!'', where one or more \wb{} denotes a word boundary.
And I want TeX upon seing my word boundaries, to decide according to internal rules whether this needs a space inserted or not.
For example No\wb{}Spaces needs a space so that TeX creates No Spaces. But Spaces\wb{}! does not need a space (before the !) and TeX creates Spaces!.
The context is that I create TeX documents dynamically, from HTML, via a computer program which utilises a state machine. And I keep appending TeX content to the total document depending on what HTML tag I encounter. (PLEASE, this question is not about how to do HTML2TeX conversion efficient.) I don't want to make decisions about where to put a space (e.g. if I append a punctuation to some word then I should decide not to add a space in between, but if I append another word then I should add a space) because this becomes very complex for me. I want TeX to make these decisions internally, e.g. like hyphenating for different languages. And so I thought that it would be a solution if instead of spaces I add the word boundaries and TeX decides whether these word boundaries need to be replaced by a space or nothing at all.
I need this solution to work with latex, pdflatex and xelatex.
I asked a similar question but it was oversimplified and confused people : I want LaTeX to handle word's before-after spaces automatically without me adding spaces
Update: adding this example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\begin{document}
He said: ``\xspace Look\xspace \emph{Mummy\xspace !\xspace no}\xspace Spaces\xspace!\xspace ''

blah\xspace (\xspace see\xspace here\xspace)\xspace .
\end{document}

The above works fine except when preceeding is opening quote/bracket and adds a space after it. I would prefer not to have a space there. And I would prefer not to make this decision but let TeX decide that.

I have read your previous question and this one and I have to admit I am rather confused by it. In the example you give here "Look \emph{Mummy! no} Spaces!'' would already give the correct output in LaTeX, so why would you want to remove spaces, add word boundaries, and ask LaTeX to put the spaces back where they were? If that is not the actual input, then please show an example of input where this is actually a problem.

You already got the relevant answer (xspace) and if that doesn't work for you you should show an example of a problem. (Imho it would be much better and faster if your code would remove spaces before punctuation. )

I don't see what answer this can have that is different to your last one. (a) don't do it, (b) if you must do it use \xspace.  If you have a case where xspace makes a wrong decision then make an example and ask about that. Otherwise I think this is a duplicate question. or perhaps a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180714/1090

@UlrikeFischer snap.

@DavidCarlisle so slow

I have added an example as to where the \xspace solution fails. PLEASE! (sorry for my tone): the question is: can I let TeX decide where to put spaces between words? PLEASE!

@bliako You can't do this directly with an TeX internal system since TeX does not contain an algorithm to predict space locations. With xspace you can do this partially in the macro layer, but unless you are using LuaTeX taking anything before your inserted command into account will be severely limited. You could wrap your entire block in a macro and in there process the text token by token, but that would be
very slow for any non-trivial amount of text.

xspace looks forward, it can not see the ( before, but there is absolutely no reason for you to add \xspace before words, just fix the insertion template.
